# C# reference to a dll file i created doesn't work as it should

Tags: c#, database, dll, reference

i'm using microsoft visual C# 2010 express to write a form program to read and write to an access database.

i created a class that is designed to read/write to the database file, saved it under a namespace and created a dll from it.

it is set as ".net Framework 4"

in my main program i added the reference to the dll file but when i try to add it to the code with

```
using Database;
```

it won't work even that the Database is in the reference of the namespace.

am i doing something wrong? or is there another way to use the commands from Database in my main program other then copying it to it?

// update //
solved
added public to all database public and DataBase db = new DataBase();

**DATABASE.cs is use it for dll**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Database
{
    public class DataBase
    {

        public DataBase()
        {
        }

        public void ItemInsert(string name,string creator,string publishing,string itemType,string genere, string year)
```

the main program

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Database;


namespace library
{
    public partial class newItemForm : Form
    {

        private void btnConfirmNewItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataBase db = new DataBase(); //this solved it
            db.ItemInsert(txtItemNameType.Text, txtEditorType.Text, txtCreatorType.Text, comboBoxType.Text, txtGenereType.Text, txtYearType.Text);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the full name of the type you are trying to use? name and containing namespace

Comment: Is the class you're trying to use `public` in the namespace Database?

Comment: @user501160, please update your question with 2 lines from your Database class' file: `namespace XXXXX` and `??? class Database` so it is possible to make better suggestion. BTW, easier way to add namespace is to type class name and let VisualStudio to add namespace itself by clicking on small rectangle next to class name in sources.

Comment: `using Database;` is _not_ 'adding a reference'. You need Project|Add Reference to do that.

Comment: added in the first post
solved by added public to all database functions and itself
and adding DataBase db = new DataBase();
 so with db.ItemInsert() i can use it now

thx

Answer (score 1):

You also need to `Add a Reference` to said assembly in your current project. The `using` statement brings a referenced assembly into scope...

Answer (score 1):

right click you project in visual studio, select `add refrence` then choose `Browse` tab, then find the poject folder and get in  bin -> debug and then you will see the dll choose it. visual studio will add it to your refrences, now you need to add a using on top of the pages  you want  it like this:

```
using mydllName;
```

if you didnt find your dll:
Load the librery project agian and right click in visual studio and press `Build` it will generate the dll.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a reference to the assembly you created. The point of creating an Assembly is not that you don't have to "copy it" to another project, but rather that you don't have to duplicate code.